# redirect to another page after selecting radiobutton in mvc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have search box and add and edit buttons in one page.i have to edit a detail after selecting radiobutton.The script for selecting radiobutton and redirecting to next page is given below.But only alert to 'Select resume' only works.rest of code is not working.Pls help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
         var which_button;
         var rad;
         $('input[type="image"]').click(function (event) {
         process_form_submission(event);             
         if (which_button == "Edit") {
             if (!$("input[name='rdoUserId']:checked").val()) {
                 alert('Select a Resume!');
                 return false;
             }
             else {
                 rad = $("input[name='rdoUserId']:checked").val();
                 var url = "Edit/" + rad;

                 $('#frmIndexResume').attr("action", url);
                 $('#frmIndexResume').submit();
             }
         }            
         return false;
     })
     function process_form_submission(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         //var target = $(event.target);  
         var input = $(event.currentTarget);
         which_button = event.currentTarget.value;
     }
 }); 
</script>
<form name="frmIndexResume" method="get"action="">
<table id="tblSearch">
<tr>
<td>Name:@Html.TextBox("Names")</td>
<td>From:@Html.TextBox("FromDate")</td>
<td>To:@Html.TextBox("ToDate")</td>
<td><input type="image" value="Search" src="@Url.Content("~/images/Search.png")"   width="60px"height="40px" alt="Search"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="Createbtn">
  <tr>
<td>
  <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Resume")" title="Create">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/Create.png")" width="40px" height="30px"alt="Create"/></a>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="image" value="Edit" src="@Url.Content("~/images/Edit.png")" width="40px" height="30px" alt="Edit"/>       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tblResume">
<caption>Listings</caption>
<tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>        
    <th>
        DOB
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
     <td>
     <input type="radio" value="@item.Id" name="rdoUserId" />       
    </td>  
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>        
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DOB)
    </td>

   </tr>
}

</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the radio button in a loop causing there to be duplicates of the radio button.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...
    <input type="radio" value="@item.Id" name="rdoUserId" />   
    ...    
}
```

The 'name' attribute is not a unique identifier. My guess is the jQuery is picking either the last or first radio button in the form since there is more than one of them.

There may be more issues besides this with the form also.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) is what you are looking for.
You can easily redirect via:

```
window.location = url;
```

or via:

```
window.navigate(url);
```

Please note that the second approach maybe ie-specific.